# python: Insert a value into a Link at the given index

Tags: python, generics, linked-list

Here is the question:

```
def insert(link, value, index):
    """Insert a value into a Link at the given index.

    >>> link = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3)))
    >>> insert(link, 9001, 0)
    >>> link
    Link(9001, Link(1, Link(2, Link(3))))
    >>> insert(link, 100, 2)
    >>> link
    Link(9001, Link(1, Link(100, Link(2, Link(3)))))
    >>> insert(link, 4, 5)
    Index out of bounds
    """
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
```

What I have written down which doesn't work well is :

```
i = 0
link_new = link(link.first)
while link.rest != Link.empty and i < index:
    link_new = link.rest
    i += 1
    if i == index:
        link_new.first = value
        link_new.rest = link.first, link.rest
    else: 
        print ("Index out of bounds")
```

Please help me to fix it!

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what is your goal, and how should this program behave?

Comment: How does Link object look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion for this

```
def insert(link, value, index):
    if index == 0:
         link.first = value

    elif link.rest != Link.empty:
          insert(link.rest, value, index-1)

    else       
        print ("Index out of bounds")
```